# transaction that was included in a block without my permission

Tags: blockchain.info, theft

After requesting for bitcoin it automatically sent to my blockchain wallet after that it was then sent out without my permission again to another address and it never arrived in my final balance but yet my total received transaction keeps increasing am so confuse about were the money went to .please help me understand

Comment: Your question is confusing, can you rephrase it to state what you expected to happen, and then what actually happened? It may help to include tx IDs or relevant bitcoin addresses.

Comment: i signed up on blockchain.info were i moved all my funds to by requesting payment after which my funds were then sent to my blockchain wallet .so i only did 4 transaction which was receiving but then i saw 2 transaction that was sent out leaving my final balance on 0.00 but i can only view my funds in the total received and its unspent

Comment: Here is my wallet  1CZBgrdzSKWFn2h1J553vqosRv6XGuV5Ts

Comment: Here is a statement of my transaction

Comment: Transactions
No. Transactions 6 
Total Received $ 10,314.02 
Final Balance $ 0.00

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is a difference between a wallet and an address. Namely, a wallet may control the keys for many addresses.

Checking the address you posted, it clearly has no bitcoins in it, as they have been transferred out to two different addresses:

15748uoft3CUiwvAqzPrLNxNxKNRpKpjt6

1EnD6fRsuajQm6B2KkYENE86nEvoinTjU8

If your wallet controls these addresses then you have nothing to worry about.

If not, then I’m sorry to say it appears your BTC was stolen. You’ll want to never use that wallet again, and it may be with spending some time trying to uncover how your wallet was hacked. Did you share login or wallet backup/seed info with anyone? Did you back it up to a potentially compromised email or Dropbox account? Etc

Your chance of recovering those coins is likely very slim, so at least you can try to learn from a past mistake.

Comment: But my balance keep increasing with each day in my total received and yes i can see the transactions of this wallet activity in a block

Comment: It says to know you wallet balance is by knowing your unspent output

Comment: When you log into your wallet, what does the balance say? I'm not talking about looking at the balance of specific addresses. Just what it says for your total balance once logged in. Does your wallet include any watch-only addresses?

Comment: Summary
Address 1CZBgrdzSKWFn2h1J553vqosRv6XGuV5Ts
Hash 160 7ebf9d97dd8d9a13b2690b22948b3e8b42205b78
Tools Related Tags - Unspent Outputs
Transactions
No. Transactions 6 
Total Received 1.17042399 BTC 
Final Balance 0 BTC

Comment: I think you still misunderstand the difference between an address, and a wallet. The balance of that address is zero. I'm not sure what else to tell you. If you control that address, but were not the one to spend it's UTXOs, then it looks someone stole your coins.

Comment: Please make me understand

Comment: On my dashboard my blockchain balance shows $0.60

Comment: A bitcoin wallet will manage your addresses and keys automatically, so each wallet can contain many keys (and addresses). As a user, you just need to think about the wallet total balance, not the balance of each address. If your wallet dashboard balance shows $0.60, then it is clear that your wallet no longer controls the bitcoins that were once in the 1CZBgr.. address. If you were not the one that send the bitcoins somewhere else, then it looks like your bitcoins were stolen.

Comment: But how is it possible that someone would be stealing my coins with all the security check i did ,it is said that my wallet has been included in a block .. 517931

Comment: Am sorry but i really am new to blockchain and its a lot of money to lose right now

Comment: Wallets are not included in blocks, transactions are. There could be a number of ways your wallet was hacked into, if you had 2FA in place the attacker may have bypassed it by getting access to your seed phrase or backup files, that would allow them to create a new instance of your wallet on another machine. Sorry for your losses.

Comment: here is the transaction address....ba762915bd4dc00a5a0764b78ffc2f02882eeb058a5921662138ba6ddb0b1bb7

Comment: I think am confusing everyone because am new on blockchain i have the transaction that was included in the block 517931